# How do I change the alignments of a widget and all of its descendants in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

I would like to align all my widgets to the top left in my app. To do this, it seems like I have to keep wrapping them with Align() all over the place. I would like to wrap the top of the tree once with something that makes everything below it aligned with `Alignment.topLeft`.

Here is the code I have:

```dart
                Column(
                  children: [
                    Align(
                        alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                        child: Text(
                            "Average Time: ${avg(_askTimesMs).round()}ms")),
                    Align(
                        alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                        child: Text("Timings (ms): $_askTimesMs")),
                  ],
                ),
```

Here is the code I want, conceptually:

```dart
                AlignDescendents(
                  alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                  child: Column(
                    children: [
                      Text(
                          "Average Time: ${avg(_askTimesMs).round()}ms"),
                      Text("Timings (ms): $_askTimesMs"),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,` on Column widget,default it is centered. `mainAxisAlignment` is start by default.

```dart
Column(      
  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
  children: [
```

Find more about [layout](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/ui/layout)

Comment: This solves the problem I showed in my code example, although I guess it doesn't solve the problem I stated in prose above: how to set the alignment for all descendants.

Comment: Creating another wrapper widget is unnecessary, that's why I've skipped that.

Comment: I see what you mean. In practice, your solution meant just a few additional lines instead of lots of additional lines and nesting.

Comment: yap, it is provided the flutter, if you need more than this, you can create wrapper widget. you can check attached link how layout works on flutter.